# how to config DNS in DHCP network in windows 2008 server R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, iis-7, dhcp

I have dynamic IP assigned on my server and server connects with my router where I bind raw static IP, I have installed DNS and Active Directory, but I am not able to setup DNS it says  "you should have atleast one startic IP in your PC "

Note : I have Windows 2008 Server R2 in my pc.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install DNS on a server with a DHCP assined IP. You must give the server a static IP address.

Comment: but when i config that with DHCP assign ip address, my internet connect will goes off. only lan was work

Comment: You have several choices here, without more info its hard to advise you specificly. You should probaly let a router of some type handle your internet connection and DHCP, then staticly assign an IP in the same range to your server. Next have the rtr point DNS traffic to that IP.

Comment: is there any other DNS software which can support DHCP ?

Comment: The reason is if the IP where to change then DNS would not work. If your RTR is doing your DHCP you can pick an IP that is in the subnet range but not part of the DHCP scoop. For example if the DHCP on is doing 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.100 and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0  then you can use anything in the 192.168.1.101-254 as static.  Does that help?

Comment: ok i will try this

Comment: is there any other free DNS software ?, i have to start hosting service in my server

Comment: DNS comes free with windows, linux, etc.

Comment: i try this but , when i setup active directory, active directory takes too long time to setup and config DNS service

Answer (score 0):

Most common practice would be to transfer the dhcp server to the future domain controller:

- write down your routers dhcp configuration
- turn off the dhcp server on your router
- configure your servers nic to use a free static ip address
- install ads/dns
- install dhcp server on your server, configure accordingly (see first step) with the needed changes